# Asymptote graph not appearing in TexPad (Texifier)

Tags: asymptote, texpad

To clarify, I'm using the latest version of MacTex as my compiler, instead of the Texifier built in one.

Recently, while trying to get Asymptote to work in LaTeX, I've run into some issues. The files compile perfectly fine: there are no error messages, no warning messages, nothing. Here's the issue however: no asymptote graph actually shows up. I have no idea how or why that happens.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
Hello.  
I like to make pics with Asymptote like this one:
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{asy}
    import graph;
    size(1inch);
    filldraw(circle((0,0),1),yellow,black);
    fill(circle((-.3,.4),.1),black);
    fill(circle((.3,.4),.1),black);
    draw(arc((0,0),.5,-140,-40));
  \end{asy}
\end{figure}
\par It makes me happy, 
since I can still type my normal LaTeX stuff around it: 
\(\int_0^{\pi}{\sin{x}}\,dx=2\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are different packages for including Asymptote in LaTeX documents. With one of those packages you need to run Asymptote manually or through a build chain in between two LaTeX runs. With another package Asymptote is run automatically but you need the `-shell-escape` compile option. I'm not sure how to set build chains in TexPad, but it would help if you show the code for a minimal document that demonstrates how you currently try to include Asymptote drawings, to establish what the correct procedure for compiling should be.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the response! I'm using the package built into MacTex, and I do have -shell-escape turned on. For my documents, I'm simply adding asymptote as a package before using \begin{asy}. Here's an example that I ripped form AoPS https://pastebin.com/g5YugJqE. The image doesn't appear, everything else does, but this is the general idea of what I'm trying to do in my actual document.

Comment: It works well on overleaf www.overleaf.com